# How to set correct firebase realtime security rules for a presence system

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

When a device (tested on iOS) is left with the app open for a long time, and the phone auto locks, the onDisconnectOperation does not trigger on the database. I suspect this is because the token expires before the user goes offline. Is there a way to make the security rules allow this?

I have already tried setting security rules to

```
 ".write" : true
```

for the node that keeps track of the connected status of the user.